# Prevent user scrolling but allow scrolling via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I have a scrollable `<div>` and I need to prevent the user from scrolling. But at the same time, JavaScript should be allowed to scroll it.

Previously, I've tried setting `overflow: hidden;` but in some browsers/os it didn't let JavaScript scroll. I've tried setting `overflow: auto;` and hiding the scrollbar and then in JavaScript listening for `wheel` events and calling `preventDefault()` but that did nothing. I can't listen for `scroll` events because then it prevents JavaScript from scrolling too.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button#scroll');
const cnt = document.querySelector('div#container');

btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  cnt.scrollTo(20, 500);
});
```

```css
div#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
div#container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="scroll">Click to scroll</button>

<div id="container">
  <img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br>
  <img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br><img src="https://p.turbosquid.com/ts-thumb/bK/x6a3nk/nlMteHHm/r1/jpg/1590782525/600x600/fit_q87/f469b1b09d4935ef73b0746eb4b77fbe06b57293/r1.jpg">
  <br>
</div>
```

Any ideas?
TYIA

Comment: Do you have some set-up code we can use? I can't be bothered to spend 5 minutes writing it myself. It's also in [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @caTS I've added a snippet now

Comment: https://devforhelp.com/code2.html can you check here but the problem is it scrolling  only once. Do you want to scroll every time onClick ? also I have tested on iPhone 13 it seems working

Comment: @devforhelp that's good, if you post the code in an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `overflow-y: hidden` to make sure the scrolling position can only be changed by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

view-source:https://devforhelp.com/code2.html

Please open the link and check the source code

Comment: Please put the code, plus an explanation of how it solves the problem, into your answer, otherwise there is a danger that your answer will be useless to future readers e.g.should your personal site disappear.

Comment: Thank you and I will make sure from next time